# JCombobox drop-down list is not large enough to show all items

Tags: java, swing, components, jcombobox

When I run the application and I click on the JCombobox for the first time, the drop-down list looks like this

[image]

The second time I click, it seems to rearrange everything and all items are shown.

[image]

Any idea why this may be happening?
I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [tour], then learn [ask] a good question and learn how to make a [mcve] and post it in your question in code format, not in an image not in external sites. This will lead to less confusion, more, faster and better answers :) Otherwise your question might get closed because it lacks these things

Comment: *"SOLVED: I was adding JComboBox instance before adding its items."* Don't write the solution in the question. Either create your own answer below, or completely delete the question. And in future, post an MCVE rather than screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: I was adding the JComboBox instance to the panel before adding the items to the JComboBox.

Answer (score -1):

Check the height property, may be it is collapsing with other component. Design and placement of the component should be correct in swing to behave properly.

Comment: This is not an answer. You don't have enough rep. yet to make comments, so please restrict your posts to things you *can* answer.

Comment: Thanks Andrew Thompson for the comment. I am working on a swing app for one of my client. It happened to be one of the problem I faced during GUI creation, I made it work by properly positioning and rearranging the jcombobox. Because submit button was sticked to jcombobox so i rearranged well. I dont know why but it worked. I thought this can be the answer so posted. Anyways Thanks for notifying :)

Comment: It's at *"I dont know why"* that you should  realise you don't have enough experience with Swing and instead of offering advice, be *asking* questions,  because *"..but it worked."* ..it probably only worked on that machine, with that PLAF, and unless the app. was resized. ***Start*** giving advice when you can make a robust, resizable cross-platform GUI ***and*** explain why it works.